# click function not working on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to take input from user in a text area and then parse those sentences in an array and then make each sentence clikcable so that clicked sentence should get copied to another text box. So to achieve this I tried creating span elements in the text area and each span would have class sentence so that on click it would copy that sentence to another text area. But the innerHTML wont produce the spans. Instead it plainly writes it in the textarea as a string.

```js
document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {
  var lines = $('#input').val().split(".");

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

    var line = lines[i];

    var para = document.getElementById("output");
    var htmlButton = ' <span class="sentence">' + line + "</span>";

    para.innerHTML = para.innerHTML + htmlButton;
  }
};



$('.sentence').click(function(e) {
  console.log("%00");
  var sentence = $(this).text();
  $('#textplace').html(sentence);
});
```

```css
#input {
  height: 150px;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

.sentence {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

body {
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




</head>


<body>

  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Enter multiple lines of things here and it will be converted to a Javascript array format.</div>
  <textarea id="input" class="u-full-width" placeholder=""></textarea>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <input id="go" class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Go!">

  <textarea id="textplace"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

After changing the textarea to division, the innerHTML works but the click function on class sentence does not work.

Comment: You need to be specific with your question. \post code which is not working then we will see what you are doing wrong. Questions like these tend to be opinion biased which is wrong in the StackOverflow forum.

Comment: I changed my question accordingly, kindly check this out now.

Comment: The probelm has been solved. Thank you for considering my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line number 7 you have done a mistake change

```
//para.innerHTMl
para.value
```

Why because you are trying to access the textarea element which is having a attribute value not innerHTML to get the data. You can use innerHTML for 'div','p' tags etc.

Comment: Instead of textarea i tried using division and the innerHTML worked, but the para.value is giving the response as para.innerHTML for textarea.